# Creating a unique constraint on two columns together in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

How do you create a unique index on two columns in Ecto, which would correspond to this:

```
CREATE TABLE someTable (
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 int NOT NULL,
    primary key (col1, col2)
)
```

?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

A Little follow up on Patrick's answer

Using only create unique_index on your model will ultimately throw an exception instead of giving you an error.

To get an error add a constraint on your changeset but as a paremeter you can give the index name created by unique_index.

So in your migration file :

```
create unique_index(:your_table, [:col1, :col2], name: :your_index_name)
```

Then in your changeset :

```
def changeset(model, param \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  |> unique_constraint(:name_your_constraint, name: :your_index_name)
end
```

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer imo.  
@TheSquad, does :name_your_constraint need to be either :col1 or :col2 in this context?  
Reference: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#unique_constraint/3

Comment: absolutely not, you can put any atom you want to have a comprehensive error message when the constraint is not met

Comment: The second parameter to `unique_constraint` (`:name_your_constraint` in the example) is meant as the name(s) of the column(s). You can use some fantasy name but if you want the error to appear at the right place e.g. in a Phoenix form you should take the name of the column/form field to which the error belongs.

Answer (score 13):

You can create a unique index across multiple rows with

```
create unique_index(:some_table, [:col1, :col2])
```

I suppose if you want to have composite keys, you need to use [`execute/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#execute/1) to run your SQL manually. Not sure how well composite keys work with Ecto though, I generally just stick with the standard serial id per table.

If you should go with the composite key approach, I think that the `NOT NULL` constraints are not necessary. The composite key should already enforce that the columns are not null.

Comment: How to add this to the changeset as an error?

Comment: @Thomas see accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

[`unique_index/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#unique_index/3) would **not** create a composite primary key as is shown in the question's example. It does create a unique constraint.

If you do want to create a composite primary key (note: not recommended when working with Ecto), [there's more information here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180216105204/http://phoenixframework.org/blog/custom-primary-key):

***Migration:***

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.Repo.Migrations.CreatePlayer do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:players, primary_key: false) do
      add :first_name, :string, primary_key: true
      add :last_name, :string, primary_key: true
      add :position, :string
      add :number, :integer
      ...
```

***Schema:***

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.Player do
  use Ecto.Schema

  @primary_key false
  schema "players" do
    field :first_name, :string, primary_key: true
    field :last_name, :string, primary_key: true
    field :position, :string
    field :number, :integer
    ...
```

In most cases [`unique_index/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#unique_index/3) is what you want, though.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post, but I ran into this today.  Remember that a unique *constraint* is not the same as a unique *index* (at least, not in all versions of PostGres -- there seems to be some movement on this). In Ecto, it seems that currently the only way to add a constraint that is not an index is to use `execute/1` in your migration, e.g.

```
defmodule YourMigration do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    execute(
      "ALTER TABLE pre.yourtable ADD CONSTRAINT something UNIQUE (something)"
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: `change` probably needs to be split into `up` and `down` functions to be able to rollback the migration.