# Ecto: Two unique fields

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've created two unique indexes on fields in the same table, and want to validate them using unique_constraint/3, however, the error message on the front-end only displays for either field, not both if they are not unique. How can I make both errors show up if neither field is unique?

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Comment: You might be looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37859294/3142192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Changeset.unsafe_validate_unique/4](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#unsafe_validate_unique/4) to find all the unique validation errors and report them to the user. `unique_constraint` must also be used to handle potential race condition of the data changing before the new record is inserted.

```
changeset
|> unsafe_validate_unique([:email], MyApp.Repo, message: "email is already in use")
|> unsafe_validate_unique([:phone], MyApp.Repo, message: "phone number is already registered")
|> unique_constraint(:email)
|> unique_constraint(:phone)
```